# Sinon stubbed method no longer stubbed when using underscore delay

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

So I'm writing javascript unit test using [sinon stubs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs/). The stubbed method is called in the code is wrapped in a delay ([underscore delay](http://underscorejs.org/#delay)). However, the actual method is getting called rather than the stub. When I don't use delay, it works as expected and calls the stub. I've included an example below of what the code looks like.  Any idea what might be going on? One hypothesis I have is that sinon is keeping track of references of someObject to restore the stub, and since I'm using a delay, someObject falls out of scope and the stub is restored to the actual method.

```js
// This is code form the unit test.
// someObject.someFunction is stubbed
sinon.stub(someObject, 'someFunction', function() {
 console.log('stubbed someFunction');
});
someObject.execute();




// These methods are defined within someObject
execute: function() {
 _.delay(
  function() {
   this.someFunction();
  },
  1000
 );
}

// This is called from the unit test despite being stubbed.
// However, when the _.delay() is removed, the stubbed
// method is called.
someFunction: function() {
 console.log('real someFunction');
}
```

Comment: I would have the same guess on what is wrong: the original is restored by the time the delay is up. Either remove the delay, wait until the delay is up, or wait for the stub to "alert" that it is done before exiting the unit test (guessing you would have more than just what you show).

Comment: @crashmstr, yes you're correct that's not all the code.  I'm also using qunit.async() so that it waits before the test exists.